# How can I append an ObjectID in an array through Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am converting a SQLite database to a MongoDB database using pymongo. I can't seem to be able to update the related fields with the ObjectIds.

In javascript, my Articles schema is the following:

```
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
    required: true,
  },
});
```

And the categories model is:

```
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  weigth: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  articles: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Article",
    },
  ],
});
```

The data is in a database and I just fetch it and iterate over all the rows with a double join query, so I get the category as well. My problem is trying to append the article id to the category *articles* array in python, or the equivalent of a javascript *push*. The code that I am trying is the following:

```
for row in rows:
    # get the category
    cat = categories.find_one({'name': row[4]})

    cat_id = str(cat['_id'])
    # populate the article
    article = {
        'title': row[0],
        'body': row[1],
        'category': str(cat["_id"])
    }

    id = articles.insert_one(article).inserted_id

    categories.update({
        '_id': cat_id
    },
        {
        '$push': {'articles': id}}
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query never matches the _id of the category.

If you replace `cat_id = str(cat['_id'])` by `cat_id = cat['_id']`

then it should work. because your `categories.update({'_id': cat_id})` does not match the ID since you don't query for `ObjectId` but for a `string`. Or in other words `ObjectId('5ea48b3743183ad74f6987bc') != '5ea48b3743183ad74f6987bc'`